# Trying to place multiple Bootstrap Thumbnails side-by-side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

taking a beginner HTML/Bootstrap/CSS etc. course so I'm pretty new to all of this.

I'm trying to align these three "Bootstrap Thumbnail Custom Content" elements next to each other, but I don't have any idea how: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Avn.jpg

I basically need to make it look like it does on their site: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails

Here's my code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="images/obliviontn.jpg" alt="Oblivion">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>Let's Play Oblivion</h3>
    <p>One of Grohlvana's most popular series, Let's Play Oblvion is a lengthy LP that explores Tamriel in Bethesda's epic fourth Elder Scrolls title.</p>
      <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYyV2nZW8iY&list=PLdx-MmfUterzswiJmybySBgyjMvpHFz9z" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Watch</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="images/skyrimtn.jpg" alt="Skyrim">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>Skyrim's Hidden Treasures</h3>
    <p>Grohlvana's most popular and unique series, Skyrim's Hidden Treasures explores locations in the fifth Elder Scrolls game that aren't tied to any specific quest</p>
      <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GlPlCvL5_Cs&list=PLdx-MmfUterznXKI4OVdE_N4fgusyD2LQ" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Watch</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="images/fallout3tn.jpg" alt="Fallout 3">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>Let's Play Fallout 3</h3>
    <p>The current in-progress Let's Play on Grohlvana's channel. Watch as Jack scours the wasteland in hopes to save its various inhabitants.</p>
      <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsMUfLUhZRQ&list=PLdx-MmfUterxl_AGBOuGlpH12IblhfIA3" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Watch</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Again, really new to this so please try to explain thoroughly. Not sure if this is an HTML or CSS issue.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you notice, each of your three code snippets above have the same parent container i.e. `<div class="row">`. The `.row` div is a block-level element with a `100%` width which is why your three columns aren't getting aligned in one line. What you can do is that wrap your three columns inside one single `<div class="row">` like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="images/obliviontn.jpg" alt="Oblivion">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>Let's Play Oblivion</h3>
    <p>One of Grohlvana's most popular series, Let's Play Oblvion is a lengthy LP that explores Tamriel in Bethesda's epic fourth Elder Scrolls title.</p>
      <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYyV2nZW8iY&list=PLdx-MmfUterzswiJmybySBgyjMvpHFz9z" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Watch</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="images/fallout3tn.jpg" alt="Fallout 3">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>Let's Play Fallout 3</h3>
    <p>The current in-progress Let's Play on Grohlvana's channel. Watch as Jack scours the wasteland in hopes to save its various inhabitants.</p>
      <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsMUfLUhZRQ&list=PLdx-MmfUterxl_AGBOuGlpH12IblhfIA3" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Watch</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="images/skyrimtn.jpg" alt="Skyrim">
  <div class="caption">
    <h3>Skyrim's Hidden Treasures</h3>
    <p>Grohlvana's most popular and unique series, Skyrim's Hidden Treasures explores locations in the fifth Elder Scrolls game that aren't tied to any specific quest</p>
      <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GlPlCvL5_Cs&list=PLdx-MmfUterznXKI4OVdE_N4fgusyD2LQ" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Watch</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Also, in the code which you've posted above, you were missing a lot of closing `</div>` tags.

---

Here's a demo using your code (view as full page):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="images/obliviontn.jpg" alt="Oblivion">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Let's Play Oblivion</h3>
        <p>One of Grohlvana's most popular series, Let's Play Oblvion is a lengthy LP that explores Tamriel in Bethesda's epic fourth Elder Scrolls title.</p>
        <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYyV2nZW8iY&list=PLdx-MmfUterzswiJmybySBgyjMvpHFz9z" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Watch</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="images/fallout3tn.jpg" alt="Fallout 3">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Let's Play Fallout 3</h3>
        <p>The current in-progress Let's Play on Grohlvana's channel. Watch as Jack scours the wasteland in hopes to save its various inhabitants.</p>
        <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsMUfLUhZRQ&list=PLdx-MmfUterxl_AGBOuGlpH12IblhfIA3" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Watch</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="images/skyrimtn.jpg" alt="Skyrim">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Skyrim's Hidden Treasures</h3>
        <p>Grohlvana's most popular and unique series, Skyrim's Hidden Treasures explores locations in the fifth Elder Scrolls game that aren't tied to any specific quest</p>
        <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GlPlCvL5_Cs&list=PLdx-MmfUterznXKI4OVdE_N4fgusyD2LQ" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Watch</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yptdzsgp/20/embedded/result/)**.

Comment: I believe there's nothing to worry about that since the `&` is a part of the URL structure.of YouTube and you cannot modify it.so i don't think that your professor will have any issues with that. As long as there aren't any errors in your html/css, you're good to go.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately he doesn't even accept assignments unless they pass and it's counting them as errors so he wouldn't accept it. I guess I'll link to a single video rather than a playlist.

Comment: yes, you can do that as well. By the way, please mark my answer as correct so that users can know that your query has been answered. Thank you.

Comment: I was but I couldn't find any option to do that, I found it though.